# How to find the directional derivative at every point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

> Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \right) & \text { if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0 & \text{ if } (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$ compute the directional derivatives of $f$ at every point.

---

My solution:

$(x^2 + y^2)cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})$ at $(x,y) = (p,p)$ in the direction $\vec{v}=(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$.

The partial derivatives are:

$\frac{(2p^2)cos(\frac{1}{2p^2})+sin(\frac{1}{2p^2})}{p}$ and $\frac{(2p^2)cos(\frac{1}{2p^2})+sin(\frac{1}{2p^2})}{p}$

The $\vec{v}$ becomes:
$\frac{\vec{v_1}}{\sqrt{\vec{v_1^2} + \vec{v_2^2}}}$ and $\frac{\vec{v_2}}{\sqrt{\vec{v_1^2} + \vec{v_2^2}}}$

Then the product of the partial derivatives and the vectors is:

$D_\vec{v}f(p,p) = \frac{(v_1 + v_2)2p^2cos(\frac{1}{2p^2})+sin(\frac{1}{2p^2})}{p\sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}}$

Am I correct?

Comment: $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ are components of a vector; they are scalars. It does not make sense to put arrows above the scalars.

Comment: @user1046533 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not set $(x,y)=(p,p)$: for an arbitrary point on the plane $\mathbf{R}^2$, its $x$ and $y$ coordinates are not necessarily the same.

For $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$, you simply apply the formula
$$
D_vf(x,y)=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot v=f_x(x,y)v_1+f_y(x,y)v_2.
$$
where $v=(v_1,v_2)$ is a unit vector.

For $(x,y)= (0,0)$, work with the limit definition of partial derivatives.